# Why isn't this multithreading efficient in the for loop in this code?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I want to use multithreading to speed up queries in a for loop code in Spring.

Some people say that: the thread pool get method is Blocking methods, so it is no different from writing without threads.

So how does this code work with thread acceleration in a Java loop?

Some languages, such as C# ,JS , use `await remoteCall(id)`, use 'await' Whether the same problem exists ?

```java
@Data
class ResultDto {
    private BaseData baseData;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class BaseData {
    public String baseInfo;
    public String remoteInfo;
}
```

```java
ExecutorService exector = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public List<ResultDto> queryAll(List<String> ids) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    List<ResultDto> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String id : ids) {
        ResultDto resultDto = new ResultDto();
        BaseData baseData = new BaseData();
        baseData.setBaseInfo("baseData" + id);

        //using thread  blocking ?
        String remoteResult = exector.submit(() -> remoteCall(id)).get();

        baseData.setRemoteInfo(remoteResult);
        resultDto.setBaseData(baseData);
        res.add(resultDto);
    }

    return res;
}

String remoteCall(String id) {
    return " httpUtils.get()" + id;
}
```

With my limited experience with multithread Programing, my code looks ugly.
How to improve it?
Please help me rewrite the code below.

Comment: Please don't use bold and italic in such a universal way - it makes it *harder* to read instead of easier.

Comment: Calling `get()` on a `Future` will block, so your code has a parallelism of 1.

Comment: The `.get` call makes it blocking and not run in parallel. So while you run on a different thread it doesn't make any difference. Use a `CompletableFuture` instead then wrap all of them in another `CompleteableFuture.allOf` and get the results.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. If you want to ask a new question, then post a new question, do not change the scope of an existing question by changing or adding a question, especially if your original question has been answered already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this.

```
ExecutorService exector = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public List<ResultDto> queryAll(List<String> ids) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    List<CompletableFuture> cfs = new ArrayList<>(ids.size());
    for (String id : ids) {
      CompletableFuture cf = Completableuture.supplyAsync(() -> getResult(id), exector);
      cfs.add(cf);
    }
    CompletableFuture allOfThem = CompletableFuture.allOf(cfs.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]);
 
    CompletableFuture<List<ResultDto>> allCompletableFutures = allOfThem .thenApply(future -> {
    return cfs.stream()
            .map(completableFuture -> completableFuture.join())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
});
    return allCompletableFutures.get();
}

ResultDto getResult(String id) {
    String remoteResult = " httpUtils.get()" + id;
    BaseData baseData = new BaseData();
    baseData.setBaseInfo("baseData" + id);
    baseData.setRemoteInfo(remoteResult);
    ResultDto resultDto = new ResultDto();
    resultDto.setBaseData(baseData);
    return resultDto;
}
```

This will give you a non-blocking solution (it will only block in the end).

Or you can make it even easier and just use a `parallelStream` and use the default fork-join pool.

```java
public List<ResultDto> queryAll(List<String> ids) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    return ids.parallelStream().map(id -> getResult(id)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

ResultDto getResult(String id) {
    String remoteResult = " httpUtils.get()" + id;
    BaseData baseData = new BaseData();
    baseData.setBaseInfo("baseData" + id);
    baseData.setRemoteInfo(remoteResult);
    ResultDto resultDto = new ResultDto();
    resultDto.setBaseData(baseData);
    return resultDto;
}
```

You can probably decide which is better to read...

Answer (score 2):

> Some people say that: the thread pool get method is Blocking methods, so it is no different from writing without threads.

They are correct.  If you call `get()` at that point, it immediately blocks until the that particular task has completed.  So the 2nd task isn't submitted until the first one completes ... and so on.

What you need to do is submit all of the tasks before calling `get()`. Something like the following pseudo-code.

```
List<Future> futures
for each id in ids:
   futures.add(executor.submit(...))

for each future in futures:
   result = future.get()
   results.add(process(result))
```

If you can arrange that each task does the processing of its result, you potentially get more parallelism.

As noted, you could use `CompleteableFuture.allOf` instead of the second loop.